# Querying in elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch. And I have two documents which are JarFileData and ClassData. I have linked those two documents with jarFileId field.

This is the ClassData

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59881021e950041f0c6fa1fa"),
"ClassName" : "Exception",
"jarFileId" : "JAR-0001",
"dependencies" : [ 
    {
        "dependedntClass" : "java/lang/RuntimeException",
        "methodSignature" : "<init>"
    }, 
    {
    {
        "dependedntClass" : "java/awt/EventQueue",
        "methodSignature" : "isDispatchThread"
    }, 
    {
        "dependedntClass" : "Exception",
        "methodSignature" : "setStackTrace"
    }
]
}
```

This is JarFileData

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59881021e950041f0c6fa1f7"),
"jarFileName" : "Client.jar",
"jarFileId" : "JAR-0001",
"directory" : "C:\\Projects\\Test\\Application",
"version" : null,
"artifactID" : null,
"groupID" : null
}
```

I want to give a directory and get all jarFiles in that directory and use it to find the dependent classes in ClassData type for those jarFiles.

This is the function I used in node.js for retrieving jarFileData type for a given directory.

```
const test = function test() {
let body = {
  size: 20,
  from: 0,
  {
   query: {
     match: {
       directory: 'C:\\Projects\\Test\\Application'
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

I am trying to use the resultset from the above query to query classData type. 
I am stuck in this part for a long time and don't know how to do it in elastic-search. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? It might also be noted that the mongodb query attempts here are actually run from the "shell". Your elasticsearch queries would need to be run from the actual language environment you want to implement in. So it would help you at least show what you are trying so your question can be answered in the context of the actual environment you are using. Which will not be the mongodb shell.

Comment: I am trying to query elastic-search with node.js. I have tried to and succeeded with simple queries but I couldn't do complex queries which I need to do.

Comment: Yes we can read. What **you** are being asked to provide is "some code showing your attempt at doing so". Without which this becomes a *"Write my code for me"* question of which many people will choose to ignore. Show an "attempt" and people are generally happy to help with "corrections/usage" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can go further, there are two steps that needs to be done:

- `jarFileId` and `dependedntClass` fields should be mapped as a `keyword` type (if this is a problem you can use [multi-field field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) of `keyword` type, and use them in query)
- `dependencies` should be [nested object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_using_literal_nested_literal_fields_for_arrays_of_objects)

Looking at your data, the joining element between these two types of documents is `jarFileId`  field. If your existing query gave you in result e.g. this list of jars:

```
{[{"jarFileId": "JAR-0001"},{"jarFileId": "JAR-0002"}]}
```

having this information, you can use this query:

```
{
   "size":0,
   "query":{
      "constant_score":{
         "filter":{
            "terms":{ "jarFileId":["JAR-0001","JAR-0002"] }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "filtered":{
         "filter":{
            "constant_score":{
               "filter":{
                   "terms":{ "jarFileId":["JAR-0001","JAR-0002"] }
               }
            }
         },
         "aggs":{
            "dependent":{
               "nested":{
                  "path":"dependencies"
               },
               "aggs":{
                  "classes":{
                     "terms":{
                        "field":"dependencies.dependedntClass"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And as a result you'll get:

```
{
    ...,
    "aggregations": {
        "filtered": {
            "doc_count": 1,
            "dependent": {
                "doc_count": 3,
                "classes": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key": "core/internal/TrackingEventQueue$TrackingException",
                            "doc_count": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "java/awt/EventQueue",
                            "doc_count": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "java/lang/RuntimeException",
                            "doc_count": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With your current model, it is not possible to do it with one query - elsticsearch does not have a join mechanism. A single document should have all the necessary information so that elasticsearch is able to decide if it matches the query or not. This is nicely described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html). So either you go with [application-side joins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html) (similar example to yours under the link) or [denormalize your data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/denormalization.html) if the performance of search is the core issue here. The only built-in "join mechanism" that I'm aware of is [Term Filter Lookup](https://www.elastic.co/blog/terms-filter-lookup) but it allows to operate only on `id` field.

Comment: Thank you very much, The thing is I want a way to use the result set of the first query in the second query. I have managed to do it separately as you have done it above. But I couldn't use the resultset of first query in the second query. Thank you once again.

Comment: This is what I have looked for, I will try to update my model and do it. Thank you so much.